# Why a function starts with @ in php ? like @unpack(xxx)?

Tags: php, function, unpack

```
$block_header = @unpack('Sc_size/Su_size/Lchecksum', fread($this->fp, 8));
```

What does this mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Error Control Operators.

it avoids showing the error returned by the function. more info in the link:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php